# How to align two div's within a div in center which works on IE11?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11

I need a header which has two div's side by side with two image tag within each.It works well on every browser except Internet Explorer 11.What should I do?Please help.Here is my code..

My html:

```
<div id="Header">
    <div id="Heder_Logo_Uttara" style="width:50%;">
        <img src="IBU_Image/uttora_bank_logo.jpg" style="width:100%; height: 130px;" />
    </div>

    <div id="Header_Right_Uttara">                         
        <img src="IBU_Image/ibankultimus.png" style="float:right; padding-top:50px;"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Header 
{ 
    width: 1000px; 
    height: 130px; 
    background-color:Green; 
}

#Heder_Logo_Uttara
{
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    width:50%;
    height: 130px;
}
#Header_Right_Uttara

{   
    float:right;
    width:50%;
    height: 130px;
}
```

Also, [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGNqaJ) is my pen which work fine except IE11. On IE11 my `#Heder_Logo_Uttara` container image go back to left side corner and `#Header_Right_Uttara` overlap left container remaining space.

Comment: Closing tag for `<div id="Header_Right_Uttara">` missing. Spelling mistake in `#Heder_Logo_Uttara`. And why are you using inline styles additionally?

Comment: Sorry @Alex it(`Heder_Logo_Uttara`) was just written by my previous colleague and I just update my code.

Comment: It's hard to understand your problem if we can't see how the images actually affect the layout. Can you at least provide the dimensions (width/height) of the images?

Comment: @Alex It also seems to me I also need to give more specific information. Now I am at home and have to wait till tomorrow to show exact code with exact image. It's first time I am questioning, so I am making mistake. Please, don't mind.

Comment: it works for me on Windows10 - IE11

Comment: I am working on windows 8.1 and IE11

Comment: Thanks guys.The problem has solved.I used conditional css for IE to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the the following conditional css and it is working fine now.

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {

        *::-ms-backdrop, #Header {
            padding-left: 250px;
            display: flex;

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things you can try:

To get the children divs to align center horizontally (which I think you're referring to in your question) you can put

```
margin:auto;
```

In the CSS for the parent div.  If you want the divs to display side by side, you can try adding

```
display: flex;
```

To the parent DIV, which will tell the div to display it's children in a row-first manner.  But like the commenters say, it'd be helpful to see the images, or perhaps a screenshot of what you're trying to accomplish, and what you're seeing in IE11.  Good luck!

Comment: `flex` is not supported on `IE9` and also partial support for `IE10` and `IE11`. You can check it http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: Thank you for letting me know!